# how to declare xmlns:local to a subfolder within my xamarin forms app?

Tags: xaml, xamarin, xamarin.forms

Hello I'm working on a xamrain forms app that has a main menu and when you click the math button it supposed to take you to the MathHome page however it crashes after you click the button on the home page

heres my code for the mathpage:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<ContentPage xmlns="http://xamarin.com/schemas/2014/forms" xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2009/xaml"
             xmlns:local="clr-namespace:SchoolTools.Math.ViewModels;assembly=SchoolTools"
             x:Class="SchoolTools.MathPage">
  <ContentPage.Resources>
    <ResourceDictionary>
      <Style x:Key="NumberStyle" TargetType="Button">
        <Setter Property="BackgroundColor" Value="White"/>
        <Setter Property="TextColor" Value="Black"/>
        <Setter Property="BorderRadius" Value="0"/>
        <Setter Property="Font" Value="36"/>
      </Style>
      <Style x:Key="OperationsStyle" TargetType="Button">
        <Setter Property="BackgroundColor" Value="#FFA500"/>
        <Setter Property="TextColor" Value="White"/>
        <Setter Property="BorderRadius" Value="0"/>
        <Setter Property="Font" Value="36"/>
      </Style>
      <Style x:Key="BackSpaceButtonStyle" TargetType="Button">
        <Setter Property="BackgroundColor" Value="Black"/>
        <Setter Property="TextColor" Value="White"/>
        <Setter Property="BorderRadius" Value="0"/>
        <Setter Property="Font" Value="Bold,40"/>
        <Setter Property="VerticalOptions" Value="CenterAndExpand"/>
        <Setter Property="HorizontalOptions" Value="CenterAndExpand"/>
      </Style>
      <Style x:Key="CleanButtonStyle" TargetType="Button">
        <Setter Property="BackgroundColor" Value="Teal"/>
        <Setter Property="TextColor" Value="Black"/>
        <Setter Property="BorderRadius" Value="0"/>
        <Setter Property="Font" Value="36"/>
      </Style>
      <Style x:Key="MainLabelStyle" TargetType="Label">
        <Setter Property="BackgroundColor" Value="Black"/>
        <Setter Property="TextColor" Value="White"/>
        <Setter Property="Font" Value="35"/>
        <Setter Property="YAlign" Value="Center"/>
        <Setter Property="XAlign" Value="Center"/>
      </Style>
    </ResourceDictionary>
  </ContentPage.Resources>

  <Grid Padding="5,0" RowSpacing="1" BackgroundColor="Black" ColumnSpacing="1">
    <Grid.BindingContext>
      <local:MainViewModel />
    </Grid.BindingContext>

    <Grid.RowDefinitions>
      <RowDefinition Height="*"/>
      <RowDefinition Height="*"/>
      <RowDefinition Height="*"/>
      <RowDefinition Height="*"/>
      <RowDefinition Height="*"/>
      <RowDefinition Height="*"/>
    </Grid.RowDefinitions>
    <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
      <ColumnDefinition Width="*" />
      <ColumnDefinition Width="*" />
      <ColumnDefinition Width="*" />
      <ColumnDefinition Width="*" />
    </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>

    <Label Grid.Row="1" Grid.Column="0"  Grid.ColumnSpan="3"
        Text="{Binding DisplayValue}" Style="{DynamicResource MainLabelStyle}" />
    <Button Text="←" Grid.Row="1" Grid.Column="3" Command="{Binding BackspaceCommand}"
        Style="{DynamicResource BackSpaceButtonStyle}" />

    <Button Text="7" Grid.Row="3" Grid.Column="0" Command="{Binding NumberComamnd}"
        CommandParameter="7" Style="{DynamicResource NumberStyle}"/>
    <Button Text="8" Grid.Row="3" Grid.Column="1" Command="{Binding NumberComamnd}"
    CommandParameter="8" Style="{DynamicResource NumberStyle}"/>
    <Button Text="9" Grid.Row="3" Grid.Column="2" Command="{Binding NumberComamnd}"
    CommandParameter="9" Style="{DynamicResource NumberStyle}"/>
    <Button Text="4" Grid.Row="4" Grid.Column="0" Command="{Binding NumberComamnd}"
    CommandParameter="4" Style="{DynamicResource NumberStyle}"/>
    <Button Text="5" Grid.Row="4" Grid.Column="1" Command="{Binding NumberComamnd}"
    CommandParameter="5" Style="{DynamicResource NumberStyle}"/>
    <Button Text="6" Grid.Row="4" Grid.Column="2" Command="{Binding NumberComamnd}"
    CommandParameter="6" Style="{DynamicResource NumberStyle}"/>
    <Button Text="1" Grid.Row="5" Grid.Column="0" Command="{Binding NumberComamnd}"
    CommandParameter="1" Style="{DynamicResource NumberStyle}"/>
    <Button Text="2" Grid.Row="5" Grid.Column="1" Command="{Binding NumberComamnd}"
    CommandParameter="2" Style="{DynamicResource NumberStyle}"/>
    <Button Text="3" Grid.Row="5" Grid.Column="2" Command="{Binding NumberComamnd}"
    CommandParameter="3" Style="{DynamicResource NumberStyle}"/>
    <Button Text="0" Grid.Row="6" Grid.Column="0" Grid.ColumnSpan="3"
    CommandParameter="0" Style="{DynamicResource NumberStyle}" Command="{Binding NumberComamnd}" />

    <Button Text="." Grid.Row="6" Grid.Column="3" Command="{Binding AddPointCommand}"
    Style="{DynamicResource OperationsStyle}"/>

    <Button Text="/" Grid.Row="2" Grid.Column="2" Command="{Binding OperatorCommand}"
    CommandParameter="/" Style="{DynamicResource OperationsStyle}"/>
    <Button Text="x" Grid.Row="2" Grid.Column="3" Command="{Binding OperatorCommand}"
    CommandParameter="x" Style="{DynamicResource OperationsStyle}" Font="25"/>
    <Button Text="-" Grid.Row="3" Grid.Column="3" Command="{Binding OperatorCommand}"
    CommandParameter="-" Style="{DynamicResource OperationsStyle}"/>
    <Button Text="+" Grid.Row="4" Grid.Column="3" Command="{Binding OperatorCommand}"
    CommandParameter="+" Style="{DynamicResource OperationsStyle}"/>

    <Button Text="√" Grid.Row="2" Grid.Column="1" Command="{Binding OperatorCommand}"
    CommandParameter="√" Style="{DynamicResource OperationsStyle}"/>

    <Button Text="=" Grid.Row="5" Grid.Column="3" Command="{Binding CalculationCommand}"
            Style="{DynamicResource OperationsStyle}"/>
    <Button Text="C" Grid.Row="2" Grid.Column="0" Command="{Binding CleanCommand}"
            Style="{DynamicResource CleanButtonStyle}"/>
  </Grid>
</ContentPage>
```

I think my  xmlns:local is messed up the class the xaml references is MainViewModel witch is in a folder in the project called Math and then sub folder within math called ViewModels

Any ideas on how to fix this issue?

Comment: It's not about the folder, what is the namespace that your `MainViewModel` is in?

Comment: the namespace is: SchoolTools.Math.ViewModels thanks for the fast reply :)

Comment: So that should be alright. What is the error message you get in your output window?

Comment: this is the error I get right after i click the button to take me to the mathpage: Xamarin.Forms.Xaml.XamlParseException: Position 37:17. The PropertyName of Label.YAlignProperty is not YAlign

Comment: here's a link to the log if you still want to look at it: http://pastebin.com/2hEu8avR

Comment: Then the problem isn't with that namespace. You set the `XAlign` and `YAlign` property of your `MainLabelStyle`. Those properties do not exist any more (or are obsolete) you should use `VerticalTextAlignment` and `HorizontalTextAlignment`

Comment: Gerald Versluis that was the issue thank you very much!

Comment: I've promoted it to an answer, please accept!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem does not seem to be in your `local` namespace declaration but seems to be in you using properties which are marked as obsolete.

Have a look at this piece of your XAML, to which your error messages refer.

```
<Style x:Key="MainLabelStyle" TargetType="Label">
   <Setter Property="BackgroundColor" Value="Black"/>
   <Setter Property="TextColor" Value="White"/>
   <Setter Property="Font" Value="35"/>
   <Setter Property="YAlign" Value="Center"/>
   <Setter Property="XAlign" Value="Center"/>
</Style>
```

If we lookup the [YAlign](https://developer.xamarin.com/api/property/Xamarin.Forms.Label.YAlign/) and [XAlign](https://developer.xamarin.com/api/property/Xamarin.Forms.Label.XAlign/) in the Xamarin Forms documentation, you'll see they are marked as obsolete. You should now use `VerticalTextAlignment` and `HorizontalTextAlignment` respectively.